How to fill blank cells created by join but keep original null in pandas
I have two dataframe, one is daily and one is quarterly
idx = pd.date_range("2023-03-31", periods=100, freq="D")
idx_q = idx.to_series().resample("QE").last()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, "a", None], "B": [4, None, 6]}, index=idx_q)


np.random.seed(42)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"C": np.random.randn(100), "D": np.random.randn(100)}, index=idx)
# resample df2 to workdays
df2 = df2.resample("B").asfreq()

# mask values larger than 0.9 in df2 with NaN
df2 = df2.mask(df2 > 0.9)

df = df2.join(df1)

I want to join them and ffill quarter data to daily.
The problem is my data have None from source and should be kept in result.
What's the right way to make this ffill?

IIUC, you can build a mask from df1 with isna and reindex:
df = df1.join(df2)

df = df.ffill().mask(df1.isna().reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=False))

Another approach could be to use a placeholder instead of NaNs in df1:
df = df1.fillna('PLACEHOLDER').join(df2).ffill().replace('PLACEHOLDER', np.nan)

Output:
              A    B         C         D
2023-03-31    1  4.0  0.496714 -1.415371
2023-06-30    a  NaN  0.496714  0.856399
2023-07-08  NaN  6.0 -0.234587 -1.142970


Mask seems a better method and replace is marked as deprecated. But how can I mask both df1 and df2. BTW, my mistake, df should be df2.join(df1), and in real world case, df2 may not contains all index in df1

@PaleNeutron replaceis not deprecated (you might however see a FutureWarning in recent versions, which you can safely ignore). IIUC, you would need out = df2.fillna('XXX').join(df1.fillna('XXX')).ffill().replace('XXX', np.nan).infer_objects(copy=False)

Is there any placeholder recommended? A random long string? Or float('inf')?

If you're sure there is no Inf in your data Inf is indeed a good idea (or -1 if no negative values). This will keep the dtype.
